# Rewrite Issue on index.html

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, directory-index

I have `index.html` on my `html_directory` on my website also I entered a rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ newindex.php
```

It seems requests to my site is routing to my index.html file , my questions are:

1. Do I need to have index.html file on my `public_html` directory or I can remove it?
2. Is my rewrite rule correct?
3. Based on my rule on `.htaccess` which page is open : `index.html` or `newindex.php`?

Answer (score 3):

Hope i understand you correctly, you want to define the entry page *newindex.php* for your directory? There is no need for rewriting, simply define which page acts as the entry page. In the .htaccess file you can define:

```
DirectoryIndex newindex.php
```

Now, if anybody calls your directory http://www.example.com, the page http://www.example.com/newindex.php will be shown. The file *index.html* is not necessary in this case, it's name is just a convention.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to set DirectoryIndex like martinstoeckli wrote I would improve your rewrite a bit:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ newindex.php [R=301,L]
```

1. you can remove the index.html - it's not needed anymore with this rule
2. no, not completely. Dots should be escaped in regexp with `\`. Because it's obviously your old entrypage you should redirect "permanent" (HTTP Statuscode 301) your page.
3. the newindex.php